# Drag and drop richfaces problem

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, richfaces

this piece of code is giving me problems (richfaces 3.3.2.GA):

```
<rich:dragIndicator id="indicator"> </rich:dragIndicator>


                     <h:dataTable id="myData" value="#{resultArray}" var="data" >
                         <h:column>
                             <a4j:outputPanel>

                                <rich:dragSupport id="myDrag" dragIndicator="indicator" dragType="sug" dragValue="#{data}" >
                                    <rich:dndParam name="name" value="#{data.name}" >
                                        </rich:dndParam>                              
                                </rich:dragSupport>
                                <h:outputText value="#{data.name}"></h:outputText>



                            </a4j:outputPanel>
                         </h:column>
                     </h:dataTable>

        <rich:panel id="myPanel">
            <f:facet name="header">Drop Zone</f:facet>
                <rich:dropSupport id="dropZone" acceptedTypes="sug" dropListener="#{dropSuggestion}" reRender="box"/>
            </rich:panel>             


        <rich:dataTable  id="box" value="#{nameList}" var="cap2">
            <f:facet name="caption">Concepts chosen</f:facet>
                <h:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{cap2.name}"/>
                </h:column>
        </rich:dataTable>
```

The action called:

```
public void dropSuggestion(DropEvent event)


             System.out.println("OntologyActions.dropSuggestions");
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();


            OntologyActions dropItem = new OntologyActions();
            String dropItemString=event.getDragValue().toString();

           //Get request items
            dropItem= (OntologyActions) event.getDragValue();

           //Locate the position of the dropped element
           int index = dropItem.resultArray.indexOf(dropItemString);

           System.out.println("String: " + dropItemString + " DropItem: " + dropItem.resultArray.get(index).name + " Index: " + index);

           //Add the element to the selected array
               selectedSuggestionsArray.add(dropItem.resultArray.get(index));
            nameList.add(dropItemString);

           //resultArray.remove(dropItem);
     }
```

The problem is, when I drop the element into the drop  zone, no actions happen, but I am sure it can see this drop zone,  because I see green or red colors, depending on the acceptedTypes.

But the concept is not removed from the container, and is not either added on the drop zone.

When I am reaching this page, I get this error:

> drop: Element with
>   [form1:j_id640:_form:myPanel] ID was
>   not found in the DOM tree.
>
> Probably element has no client ID or
>   client ID hasn't been written. DnD's
>   disabled. Check please!

And in JSF console (but just in the first attempt), debugging with firebug:

> Node was not found"  code: "8

Is this familiar to anybody??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you have defined the `dropListener` Method incorrectly. It should be `dropListener="#{beanName.dropSuggestion}"`, not only the method name I think. That would explain why no actions are being performed. I'm not sure about the other errors you get.

Comment: Ther problem was related with a4j: form and their incompatibilities.

Comment: @BlancaHdez
Did you got the solution for that even I am also facing same problem.